# bigquery: Expression 'f0_' is not present in the GROUP BY list

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to count the instances of some field values appearing in some lat/lon point. Lat/Lon are strings, so I cast them to float, and then round them to 1m (5 decimal places).

```
SELECT
  concat(ROUND(FLOAT(lat), 5),
    ROUND(FLOAT(lon), 5)),
  COUNT(field) AS fcount
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  lat,
  lon,
  fcount;
```

I would like to have, as results, the for each lat/lon concatenation, the number of times some value appears in the values of "field".

My output should look like the following tuples:

```
  lat    lon  field fcount
12.34  12.38      A     23
12.34  12.38      B     11
12.34  12.38      C     23
11.34  12.38      A     15
...
```

The query above gives me a `Expression 'f0_' is not present in the GROUP BY list` error in BigQuery. But if I put it in, it says: cannot group by an aggregate. I'd like some help in building this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query to work you should try as below  (looks like you use BigQuery Legacy SQL - so below is in Legacy SQL)

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  CONCAT(STRING(ROUND(FLOAT(lat), 5)),
    STRING(ROUND(FLOAT(lon), 5))) as latlong,
  COUNT(field) AS fcount
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY 1
```

of course, in no way it returns what then you said you expect your query to return

for this you should try below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  ROUND(FLOAT(lat), 5) lat,
  ROUND(FLOAT(lon), 5) lon,
  field,
  COUNT(field) AS fcount
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```